# Save a link to create new document in Google Docs

Tags: bookmarks, google-docs

Is it possible to bookmark a link that, when chosen, will automatically open up new document (a word processing document in this case) in Google Documents even if I don't have GD open at the time? Having such a link would be a bit of timesaver for me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can indeed. Looking at the HTTP traffic, when you click the button to create a new document, it goes to https://docs.google.com/document/create first. I've checked and you can hit this page directly and it will do just what you want.

As noted by Ava, you can also use:

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create
- https://docs.google.com/presentation/create

Comment: It's 2014 and this link still works.

Comment: To automatically open a new document in a specific folder, you can also append a url parameter for `?folder=<FOLDER_ID>`. (You can get the `<FOLDER_ID>` by noting the URL after navigating to the folder in Google Drive: `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/<FOLDER_ID>`.)

Comment: @OmarTariq they still do in 2018!

Comment: There's now a super-memorable shortened link: https://docs.new (also, https://sheets.new, https://slides.new, [others](https://twitter.com/googledocs/status/1055490445088903168)).

Comment: @AlexP.Miller Thank you so much! The `https://docs.google.com/document/create?folder=1d4AX96kMR34J0iNGABrrNg8` format is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Kevin Wow, that's definitely handy! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What Rebecca said [in her answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/6488/88163) seems to work. Also, these would be the links to spreadsheets and presentations:

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create
- https://docs.google.com/presentation/create

Answer (score 2):

From: [Create and rename documents, spreadsheets, and presentations - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/49114?hl=en)

> You can also create new documents, spreadsheets, and presentations
>   straight from the following URLs:
>
> Docs: [docs.google.com/create](http://docs.google.com/create),
>   [google.com/docs/create](http://google.com/docs/create)
>   Sheets:
>   [sheets.google.com/create](http://sheets.google.com/create),
>   [google.com/sheets/create](http://google.com/sheets/create)
>   Slides:
>   [slides.google.com/create](http://slides.google.com/create),
>   [google.com/slides/create](http://google.com/slides/create)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see there is no easy way of doing so. When you create a new document, the window that opens already has the document ID in its URL, so this means the ID must be created  and stored by Google Docs before you can actually start editing.

So I would say, no, it is not possible, because you would have to have an ID in the document editor.

Answer (score 1):

I threw the files necessary to do this properly into a github repo if anyone wants to use it! https://github.com/kyletns/quick-docs